# How to compute the JTextPane's real height and length

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

i set the max width of the JTextPane(200px) and use the method:

```
if(textPane.getPreferredSize().width> maxWidth ) {
textPane.setSize(maxWidth, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        View v = textPane.getUI().getRootView(textPane);
        v.setSize(maxWidth, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        int preferredHeight = (int) v.getPreferredSpan(View.Y_AXIS);
        textPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(maxWidth, preferredHeight));
}
```

but the height that compute is not the "real" height, it was a little heighter than needed, the width is also a litte wider than needed (about 25 px)， how to compute the real needed height when limit max width?

Comment: Is the text meant to be either editable or selectable (the latter for copying etc.)?

Comment: why? Because, dont, dont, dont is the most helpful advice in the long run. You need very special requirements for not following that.

Answer (score 2):

setPreferredSize(), setMaximumSize, etc.. behavior depends on the actual LayoutManager that has been set in your Component.

Comment: the layoutManger in the component is BoxLayout(Y_AXIS), the height that computed is not the "real" height, so if use it to set setMaximumSize etc... is not work properly.

Comment: how components are disposed and resized inside a BoxLayout depends on how you are using glue and fixed areas. Try to post more code, from these few lines I can't tell you more. Maybe @Andrew Thompson has some suggestions.

Comment: I have no intention of considering this further until the OP answers my question.  @OP:  Note that this is a discussion forum, not a help desk.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
http://java-sl.com/tip_text_height_measuring.html